# UITableView contentSize wrong when using UISearchBar

Tags: ios, ios7, uisearchbar, uitableview

`UITableView` is reporting a bigger `contentSize` than expected when using a `UISearchBar`. With zero cells, the expected content height would be zero. Instead, the following code outputs 612 in iPhone 4-inch running iOS 7.

```
@implementation HPViewController {
    UITableView *_tableView;
    UISearchBar *_searchBar;
    UISearchDisplayController *_searchController;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    _tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [self.view addSubview:_tableView];

    _searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];

    _searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:_searchBar contentsController:self];
    _searchController.delegate = self;
    _searchController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
    _tableView.tableHeaderView = _searchBar;
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    CGSize contentSize = _tableView.contentSize;
    NSLog(@"%f", contentSize.height); // 612.000000
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section { return 0; }
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { return nil; };

@end
```

Commenting the line that sets the header view makes the code output 0, as expected.

Also, if I assign an empty `UIView` as the header, the contentSize will be correct and match the height of the header. The problem only happens with `UISearchBar`.

Is there any way around this? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I'm having the same problem today with iOS 11.2. With 1 header and 1 cell in the table, I can nearly scroll all of the content off the screen. However, the contentSize has the height I am expecting on iOS 10.3.1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Placing the `UISearchBar` inside a container `UIView` mostly fixes the problem.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    _tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [self.view addSubview:_tableView];

    UIView *searchBarContainer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    _searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:searchBarContainer.bounds];
    [searchBarContainer addSubview:_searchBar];

    _searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:_searchBar contentsController:self];
    _searchController.delegate = self;
    _searchController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
    _tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBarContainer;
}
```

Unfortunately the `UISearchBar` glitches in some scenarios that I couldn't isolate yet. I opted to calculate the `contentSize` manually by adding the height of all cells.

Comment: Thanks for the tip of adding to a subview. At least for me that worked on it's own.

Comment: There is feature when searchbar hiding under the navbar automatically. Unfortunately it disappears bcs of this view-container...

Answer (score 3):

Starting from iOS11, UITableView uses estimate row/header/footer height to calculate initial contentSize by default. In fact, if you tap on the search bar and dismiss the keyboard, content size will have the correct value.

To fix this behavior, set estimate row, header and footer height to 0 in IB instead of Automatic:

[image]

or just do it programmatically:

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 0;
self.tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 0;
self.tableView.estimatedSectionFooterHeight = 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this delegate method

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
}
```

Maybe your view for footer is groing up because there is no cells to show.

Comment: That wouldn't be called. There are no sections in my sample code. The header is the table view header, not a section header.